# Query Mobile buttons not rendering on iOS 11 using WKWebView (Cordova App)

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, jquery-mobile, ios11

On my Cordova app the buttons below the scroll fold are not rendering when I scroll down. If I scroll back up then back down they sometimes reappear.

I can click on the white space where they should be and the button click event listeners are triggered.

This issue is only affecting buttons that have the `.ui-btn` class

- OS: iOS11
- Device: iPhone 7
- Cordova: ios 3.9.2
- WebView: WKWebView

Comment: did you found why this happens? Is on [Bugzilla](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=WKWebView) something useful?

Comment: @deblocker Removing the `position: relative;` property on .ui-btn fixed the issue for me but I'm not sure why.